# app crash at tableview:reloadrowsatindexpaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell and am getting data from the network 10 at a time. As users scroll down it fetches 10 more and displays the content.

Sometimes, my fetch can be a bit slow (>3-4 secs) and during that instance(when a fetch is currently happening), if my custom tableview cell is clicked (on the visible rows) then the app crashes at the following line. (I followed the example [here](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/14/iphone-uitableview-with-animated-expanding-cells/) to expand/collapse my cell and show more content)
Obviously the tableview:reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is called as and when network fetch is done and making changes to tableview data..so how can i fix this issue ?

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"ROW SELECTED..%ld",indexPath.row);
    if (self.selectedIndex ==indexPath.row)
    {
        self.selectedIndex=-1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }

    if (self.selectedIndex!=-1){
        NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedIndex inSection:0];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    self.selectedIndex=(int)indexPath.row;

    //[self.tableView beginUpdates];

   //app crashes at this line !! 
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //[self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The exception i am getting is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Can you show the codes where the fetching are?

Answer (score 1):

If self.selectedIndex!=-1 is true, then you are going to ask the tableview to reload twice. I have a few suggestions:

- put all those reload calls into dispatch blocks, so you don't issue them directly in a delegate method
- aggregate the last two reloads into a single reload by using a mutable array, but again, dispatch to the main queue.

Also, add some logs. What happens if prevPath is out of range - that cell isn't valid any more?

EDIT: your answer is here:

"The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

- Before the update you had 10 items in this section.
- After the update you had 11 items in this section
- you inserted one and deleted one (this is not shown in your code snippet)
- you didn't move any in or out

So you have one more item in your section (told to the tableview in the delegate method) than insertions (net 0) and moves (net 0).

Comment: i m not sure i understand how this will help in my current crash problem. The main issue is, the network fetch is trying to update the tableview contents at the same time as the above function when the cell is clicked. is it not? However i did consolidate as you had suggested , but still getting the same error.

Comment: When you reload, then you'd better have the same number of items in your table as you did the last time it updated. Did you log the value of prevPath? Are you calling this on the main thread? It doesn't matter if a network activity is READING your table values, but if its adding or subtracting to them that could be a problem. Start NSLoging everything - when the tableView asks for number of sections, number of items in the sections (the delegate method), and even in this method that crashes - log the number of items in your data source. There is a mismatch

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes my network activity is trying to add more data to the existing tableview. Basically i am using a pagination concept to fetch 10 rows at time and the 11th row is a loading cell(which shows the activity indicator) Hence the mismatch. As user scrolls down, i fetch the next set of 10 rows, and so the loading cell is now gone ! Maybe that could be what is causing the problem.